# Скалярное произведение векторов в Си

Tags: c, c++

Нужна программа,которая считывает параметры вектров(координаты) а после вычисляет их скалярное произведение

Comment: Насколько сильно данная программа нужна? ;-)

Comment: @a_kliimov, Это вопрос на форум [FreeLancer](http://freelancer.ru/).

Comment: @ReinRaus вот какого шаблонного комментария нам не хватает :)

Comment: Уважаемый @a_kliimov перед тем как задавать вопрос на Хэшкод сами пробуйте ришить задачу (хотябы формулы бы привели если в C++ вы NULL:) )

Comment: @a_kliimov, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: да я же просто помочь прошу

Comment: Ну вот с умножением можно помочь:

    double vecprod(int dim, double *vect1, double *vect2) {
        double  s = 0;
        for(; dim-- > 0; s+=*vect1++ * *vect2++);
        return s;
    }

dim -- размерность векторов. (сорри, сначала поставтоинкремент позабыл)

Comment: @alexlz, не кормите...

Comment: Я не кормлю, я подкармливаю.

Comment: вбейте в google Ваш вопрос - там 100500 ответов...

Comment: а в каком здесь виде ввод сделать ? можно пожайлуста,полные текст программмы

Comment: Это уже предел наглости. Хоть что-нибудь сам сделай.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор не прилагает ни малейшего усилия для решения проблемы.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Как-тот так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector{
    double X, Y;

    Vector():X(0), Y(0) {}
    Vector(double x, double y):X(x), Y(y) {}
    Vector(int x, int y):X(static_cast<double> (x)), Y(static_cast<double> (y)) {}
};

double Multiplication(const Vector &vec1, const Vector &vec2){
    Vector temp;
    temp.X = vec1.X * vec2.X;
    temp.Y = vec1.Y * vec2.Y;
    return temp.X + temp.Y;
}

void main() {
    Vector vec1(1, 3);
    Vector vec2(1, 1);

    double result = Multiplication(vec1, vec2);

    cout << result;
}
```

И почитайте тут [Линейная алгебра для разработчиков игр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131931/). Достаточно хорошо написано.